# Connect Dialogflow to Pepper - issue with HTTPSConnection

Tags: python, https, dialogflow-es, pepper

I am trying to connect Pepper to Dialogflow. The Dialogflow SDK is stored in the project folder/lib. The python version used by Pepper is 2.7. I use python 2.7.9.

```
self.folderName = os.path.join(self.framemanager.getBehaviorPath(self.behaviorId), "..\lib")

if self.folderName not in sys.path:

sys.path.append(self.folderName)

self.log(self.folderName)

import apiai

ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

When running the code, I got the errors:

```
[ERROR] behavior.box :_safeCallOfUserMethod:281 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_1338328200__root__test_1: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\PROGRA~2\ALDEBA~1\CHOREG~1.1\lib\naoqi.py", line 271, in _safeCallOfUserMethod

func()

File "<string>", line 23, in onInput_onStart

File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\PackageManager\apps\.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior\behavior_1\..\lib\apiai\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>

from .requests.query import Entry

File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\PackageManager\apps\.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior\behavior_1\..\lib\apiai\requests\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>

from .request import Request

File "C:\Users\loadedChoregrapheBehavior\behavior_1\..\lib\apiai\requests\request.py", line 9, in <module>

from httplib import HTTPSConnection

ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSConnection
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Is httplib installed correctly on the robot? Which version?

Comment: yes, it's properly installed. The version is 2.7

Comment: "Note: HTTPS support is only available if the socket module was compiled with SSL support."
Can you confirm it was?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html

Comment: Here you run it on your Windows machine. Did you try to run it on the robot ?

Comment: @VictorPaléologue Actually I could run it on the real robot. The issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

This program must be run on the robot, rather than on your computer.